# Number of subsequences of size k and sum s

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, subsequence

Consider an array A with length n. Let k be the length of subsequences to be generated. What I want to do is to get the number of subsequences with length k and sum s.

Example:

```
A = [1,1,2,2,3]
s = 4
k = 2
```

So output would be 3 -> [{1,3}, {1,3}, {2,2}].

**Note:** 1 is considered twice as treated individually.
The total number of subsequences with length k is **ⁿ**Cₖ (Here, 10).

**What I tried:** I tried to generate all subsequences of length k using Pascals Identity, individually calculate their sum and check whether it is equal to sum s or not. How can I make the algorithm more efficient?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *"Can anyone help me with this?"* would imply you made an attempt, could you show us your code, then we can help identify specific issues

Comment: This is a classic computer science problem/question.  What research have you already done?  Look up NP-Hard problems.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Do your code *work?* Then perhaps you should post on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) instead?

Comment: As you already know, this can be solved (well, most likely in your case) using dynamic programming. In a nutshell you have to do the following: 1) determine a recursive function which computes your result. 2) Add memoization (usually, to reduce complexity from exponential to polynomial). The first part may be tricky. If you can't come up with one, you should ask your instructor (or whoever told you to use dynamic programming) for help. Usually the idea is to process items one-by-one and maintain some sort of partial solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about C++ but this seems to work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <map>

double f(int A[], int n, int s, int k, int i, map<array<int, 3>, double> memo){
  if (k == 0)
    return s == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  if (i == n || s < 0 || k < 0)
    return 0;
  return memo[array<int, 3>{s, k, i}] =
    f(A, n, s - A[i], k - 1, i + 1, memo) + f(A, n, s, k, i + 1, memo);
}

int main(){
   map<array<int, 3>, double> memo;
   int A[5] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3};
   double result = f(A, 5, 4, 2, 0, memo);
   cout << result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the knapsack method. For each element you can either include it or exclude it. Here's the cpp code :

```
ll knap(int values[],int n, int i, int length, int sum) { //ll is long long
    if(s<0 || i>n-1 ||l<0) return 0;
    if(s==0 && l==0) return 1;
    ll a = knap(values,n,i+1,l-1,s-values[i]); //including current element
    ll b = knap(values,n,i+1,l,s);  //not including the current element and moving on
    return (a+b);
}
```